# Obtener datos de un XML externo a PHP

Tags: php, xml

Buen día!

Estoy intentando obtener datos en una URL externa; estos datos están en XML.

Concretamente están en esta URL:

[URL con los datos en XML](http://habbo.dance/stats.xml)

Luego estos datos necesito imprmirlos con PHP, para eso estoy usando este codigo:

```
<?php
//para llamar el Archivo xml
$url = 'https://habbo.dance/stats.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
// tomar cualquier cosa
$title=$xml->SHOUTCASTSERVER->VERSION;
// mostrar cualquier cosa
echo $title;

?>
```

Pero el resultado del código es una página vacía, no me da un error.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Gracias.

Comment: ok ya intentaste ver en el log ???

Comment: si pones un `echo "Hola Mundo";` tampoco te lo imprime???

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la URL https://habbo.dance/stats.xml no te está sirviendo un archivo válido. Al menos en mi caso da un error 502 Bad Gateway. Si eres quien sirve ese `.xml` debes velar de que sean un documento válido. Si es servido por terceros, debes contactarlos.

Vamos a probar tu código con un `.xml` válido que está en la URL:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ws-xmlschema/master/pom.xml

Y vamos a obtener varias propiedades, simples o anidadas, así como elementos de un array, y verás que funciona:

```
$url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ws-xmlschema/master/pom.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo $xml->modelVersion.PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->description.PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->issueManagement->url.PHP_EOL;
echo "mailingLists:".PHP_EOL;
foreach($xml->mailingLists->children() as $item) {
    echo "\t{$item->name}".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
4.0.0
Apache XMLSchema is a light weight schema object model that can be used to manipulate or generate XML schema.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLSCHEMA
mailingLists:
    WS Developers
    WS Users
```